# Remove duplicates from drop down list

Tags: php, sql

I'm using the code below to return a list of LastNames into a form's drop down menu.

```
<?php
    include 'conn.inc.php';
    $sql_dropdown_lastname = "SELECT LastName FROM Individuals";
    $sql_run_lastname = odbc_exec($conn_general, $sql_dropdown_lastname);
        echo "<table><form action='index.php' method='POST'><tr><td>Individual Last Name</td><td><select name='IndivSurname'>";
            while($lastname_row = odbc_fetch_array($sql_run_lastname)){
                $AllLastName=$lastname_row['LastName'];
                    echo"<option value='$AllLastName'>$AllLastName</option>";
            }

        echo"</select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'></td>
                </tr>
                </form>
        </table>";

?>
```

However several entries are duplicate. 
How would I be able to eliminate any duplicates from the drop down list ?

Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: How about `select distinct . . .`?

Comment: If in any case there is a space as prefix or suffix (which is not rendered in presentation), distinct may not have the desired result. Creating your own list with surname in lowercase in key and surname as-is as value (`$arr[$keyval]=$contentval`) and then do a `foreach` would make more sense in my opinion... But you'd have to add a few extra lines of code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are truly duplicates (and not just people with the same last name), you can do it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LastName FROM Individuals
```

Note, if they are people who are different, but have the same last name, you'd want to bring in another field in your query, such as this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LastName, FirstName FROM Individuals
```

Comment: They are duplicates because they are people with the same last name however the SELECT DISTINCT did the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: if you want to make sure those people who have the same last name but are different you'd need to add in another field in your select.  I edited it to show.

Comment: Thanks, I plan to do so at a later stage.